# How to pass object to c through nodejs adon-api?

Tags: c, node.js, node.js-addon

How to pass object to 'C' code and return Object from C code. i'm new to 'C' and i need to run one function in 'C' code then i want to sent that result to javascript.

Comment: This is documented at https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/addons.html.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand `Object from C code`, but you can use C++ code for project with [C++ Addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html), check example of it.